# how can I get a value inside Tr using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get "Test2" using JavaScript?

Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
  <th> </th>
  <tr id = "123">
    <td>
      <UL> 
        <Li> Test1 </Li>
        <Li> <a class ="SomeClass" >Test2 <a/> </Li>
      </UL>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your markup is  invalid, TR should only have TD children.

Comment: Is jQuery an option? you can do getElementById but jq is designed for this sort of stuff!

Comment: Why not you assign Id attribute and get it by document.getElementByID ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName`:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('SomeClass');
var value = a[0].innerHtml;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ4S2/)

If you are already using jQuery you can simply use

```
$('.SomeClass').text();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Shouldn't this be something like a[0].innerHTML? maybe more elements with same class.

Comment: I know is working :)... that's why I suggested the fix. Still, since he wants only the value from that parent I suggest looking for this class inside the children elements of the specified div (but since I'm typing from phone I won't add an answer).

Comment: You were correct, I had to test it on JSFiddle to make sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following JavaScript code to do it.

```js
var example = document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML;

alert(example);
```

```html
<table>
  <th></th>
  <tr id="123">
    <td>
      <UL>
        <Li>Test1</Li>
        <Li> <a class="SomeClass" id="test2">Test2 <a/> </Li>
      </UL>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: After getting the id then do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Why downvote joker's answer? Is a valid solution (although he should add var value = example.innerHTML at the end, and adding markup is not always a good way to do things).